# Green thread vs native thread vs daemon thread vs user thread

Tags: multithreading, daemon, green-threads

What is the difference between all these type difference? I am able to find diff between first two and last two but not altogether in all.
Can you please give a detailed info regarding these type with example. And do we have diff type of thread apart these thread?

Comment: maybe you can only find the difference between the first pair and the last pair because these are orthogonal concepts? What is the difference between apples, pears, red, and yellow?